# Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:

Tags: php, binding, pdo

I am attempting to use the following code to search a database using words in a search field.

For some reason I am getting the following error

> Warning: PDOStatement::bindValue() [pdostatement.bindvalue]:
>   SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are
>   1-based in..

Here is the function code:

```
// Retrieve search results
    function retrieve_search_posts($searchfield){
        //test the connection
        try{
            //connect to the database
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mjbox","root", "usbw");
        //if there is an error catch it here
        } catch( PDOException $e ) {
            //display the error
            echo $e->getMessage();

        }

        $where = array();

        $words = preg_split('/[\s]+/',$searchfield);

        $total_words = count($searchfield);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++){

            $where[] .= "`post_title` LIKE ?";

        }

        $where_string = implode(" OR ", $where);

        $query = "
                                SELECT  p.post_id, post_year, post_desc, post_title, post_date, img_file_name, p.cat_id
                                FROM    mjbox_posts p
                                JOIN    mjbox_images i
                                ON      i.post_id = p.post_id
                                        AND i.cat_id = p.cat_id
                                        AND i.img_is_thumb = 1
                                        AND post_active = 1
                                WHERE post_title LIKE ?
                                ORDER BY post_date
                                DESC";

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

        foreach($words AS $index => $word){
            $stmt->bindValue($index, $word, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        $stmt->execute();

        $searcharray = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $searcharray;
    }
```

What have I done wrong to cause the outputted error message?

Comment: Are you confirmed thaat "$searchfield" have value? because the error message exactly says, parameter count mismatch.

Comment: your not using using `$where_string` hence  `$query` has only 1 bind parram but `$words` may contain more then 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you didn't *use* the string of `...OR LIKE` clauses you carefully constructed in the loop.

Secondly, as the error says, prepared statement parameters are 1-indexed, whereas your array is 0-indexed. You need to shift all the indexes in the array up 1 in order to get it to work with your current `foreach`, or add 1 to them during the loop.

Try this instead:

```
function retrieve_search_posts($searchfield){
    //test the connection
    try{
        //connect to the database
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mjbox","root", "usbw");
    //if there is an error catch it here
    } catch( PDOException $e ) {
        //display the error
        echo $e->getMessage();

    }

    $words = preg_split('/[\s]+/',$searchfield);

    // Easy way to 1-index a 0-indexed array
    array_unshift($words, '');
    unset($words[0]);

    // Never used and meaningless - $searchfield is a string
    // $total_words = count($searchfield);

    // Tidier and more resilient than the loop
    $where_string = implode(" OR ", array_fill(0, count($words), "`post_title` LIKE ?"));

    $query = "
       SELECT  p.post_id, post_year, post_desc, post_title, post_date, img_file_name, p.cat_id
       FROM    mjbox_posts p
       JOIN    mjbox_images i
       ON      i.post_id = p.post_id
               AND i.cat_id = p.cat_id
               AND i.img_is_thumb = 1
               AND post_active = 1
       WHERE $where_string
       ORDER BY post_date
       DESC
    ";

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

    foreach ($words AS $index => $word){
        // You may want to use "%$word%" or similar below, as it is the LIKE
        // keyword in your query is doing nothing and you might as well use =
        $stmt->bindValue($index, $word, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }

    // Handle the potential error here!
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea PDO starts at [1]..code works perfectly thank you.

Comment: So you used `array_shift` and `unset` to move each value up 1 place in the array and then deleted the new empty [0] key?

Comment: Yes exactly. It's a simple approach but it works. If you need to do it in several places in your code you could wrap it in a function like `function one_index_array ($array) { array_unshift($array, ''); unset($array[0]); return $array; }` - then you can just do `$words = one_index_array(preg_split('/[\s]+/',$searchfield));`

Answer (score 1):

"1-based" isn't a very friendly error message

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type#Index_origin

1-based = minimum value is 1, so 0 (first value in php/c array) is not valid

```
    foreach($words AS $index => $word){
        $stmt->bindValue($index+1, $word, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
```

Comment: @crm In PHP indexed arrays returned by native functions are usually zero-indexed (i.e. the key of the first element is `0`). As is so often the case with PHP, when PDO prepared statements were designed the developers decided to ignore this convention and use 1-indexed markers instead, breaking what you tried to do, which is the obvious approach and should by rights work. You can easily shift the indexes in the array, see my answer.

Comment: Fair question. Starting writing a speculative answer but decided to delete it cos it was just rambling - I have no idea

Comment: @DaveRandom's answer to your comment is the articulate version of the nonsense I just wrote and subsequently deleted