# Find mismatch between variables and bound tokens in Yii

Tags: mysql, yii, pdo

I am using prepared statement to insert data. I am getting the `'Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.'` I have tried dumping the prepared statement but I can't spot the mismatch. Is there a way to figure out the mismatch.

```
  $i = 0 ; $j = 0  ; $k = 0 ; $l = 0 ;  $str = "" ; $region_str = '' ; 
  $occasion_str = '' ; $flavor_str = '' ; 


       foreach($result->WINES->WINE as $w) 
                {
                if($i == 0) 
                $str = "(:wineid$i,:acctid$i,:brand$i,:varietal$i,:descr$i,:prop$i,:color$i,:case$i,:url$i)" ;
                else
                $str .= ", (:wineid$i,:acctid$i,:brand$i,:varietal$i,:descr$i,:prop$i,:color$i,:case$i,:url$i)" ;   

                foreach($w->REGIONS->REGION as $region) 
                                               {
                                                   if($j == 0)
                                                    $region_str = "(:rwineid$i,:region$j)" ; 
                                                   else 
                                                    $region_str .= ", (:rwineid$i,:region$j)" ;
                                                 $j++ ;  
                                               }
                                           foreach($w->OCCASIONS->OCCASION as $o) 
                                               {
                                                   if($k == 0)
                                                    $occasion_str = "(:owineid$i,:occasion$k)" ; 
                                                   else 
                                                    $occasion_str .= ", (:owineid$i,:occasion$k)" ;
                                                 $k++ ;  
                                               }
                                            foreach($w->FLAVORS->FLAVOR as $f) 
                                               {
                                                   if($l == 0)
                                                    $flavor_str = "(:fwineid$l,:flavor$l)" ; 
                                                   else 
                                                    $flavor_str .= ", (:fwineid$l,:flavor$l)" ;
                                                 $l++ ;  
                                               }
                                            $i++ ;                
                                         }
                     $sql = " Delete from wines ; 
                              Insert into wines (wineid,acctid,brandname,varietal,description,propreitaryname,color,caseproduction,url)
                              values 
                              $str ; 
                               Delete from wine_regions ; 
                              Insert into wine_regions (wineid,region) values $region_str ; 
                              Delete from wine_occasions ; 
                              Insert into wine_occasions (wineid,occasion) values $occasion_str ; 
                              Delete from wine_flavors ; 
                              Insert into wine_flavors (wineid,flavor) values $flavor_str ;  " ; 
                                if($str != "")       
                                  {
                                            $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql) ; 
                                    //      $command_2 = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql_2) ; 

                                             $i = 0 ;  $j = 0  ; $k = 0 ; $l = 0 ;
                                             foreach($result->WINES->WINE as $wine) 
                                                 {

                                                   $command->bindValue(":wineid$i",$wine->WINEID,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                                        //         $command_2->bindValue(":wineid$i",$i,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                                                   $command->bindValue(":acctid$i",$wine->ACCTID,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                                                   $command->bindValue(":brand$i",$wine->BRANDNAME,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                                                   $command->bindValue(":varietal$i",$wine->VARIETAL,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                                                   $command->bindValue(":descr$i",$wine->DESCRIPTION,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                                                   $command->bindValue(":prop$i",$wine->PROPRIETARYNAME,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                                                   $command->bindValue(":color$i",$wine->COLOR,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                                                   $command->bindValue(":case$i",$wine->CASEPRODUCTION,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                                                   $command->bindValue(":url$i",$wine->URL,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;

                                                   foreach((array)$wine->REGIONS->REGION as $region) 
                                                    {

                                                      $command->bindValue(":rwineid$j",$wine->WINEID,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                                                      $command->bindValue(":region$j",$region,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                                                      $j++ ;

                                                    }
                                                   foreach((array)$wine->OCCASIONS->OCCASION as $o) 
                                                    {
                                                      $command->bindValue(":owineid$k",$wine->WINEID,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                                                      $command->bindValue(":occasion$k",$o,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                                                      $k++ ;  
                                                    }
                                                   foreach((array)$wine->FLAVORS->FLAVOR as $f) 
                                                   {
                                                      $command->bindValue(":fwineid$l",$wine->WINEID,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                                                      $command->bindValue(":flavor$l",$f,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                                                      $l++ ; 
                                                   }

                                                   $i++ ;   

                                                 } 
                                var_dump($command) ; 

                                    $command->execute() ; 

                             }
```

Comment: Show your code, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't check, if will be error - inform me in the comments. Try my code:

> ```
>     if(!empty($result->WINES->WINE))
>     {
>         $i = 0 ; $j = 0  ; $k = 0 ; $l = 0 ;
>         $arr = $region_arr = $occasion_arr = $flavor_arr = array();
>         $str = $region_str = $occasion_str = $flavor_str = array();
>         foreach($result->WINES->WINE as $w)
>         {
>             $t = array(
>                 ":wineid$i" => $w->WINEID,
>                 ":acctid$i" => $w->ACCTID,
>                 ":brand$i" => $w->BRANDNAME,
>                 ":varietal$i" => $w->VARIETAL,
>                 ":descr$i" => $w->DESCRIPTION,
>                 ":prop$i" => $w->PROPRIETARYNAME,
>                 ":color$i" => $w->COLOR,
>                 ":case$i" => $w->CASEPRODUCTION,
>                 ":url$i" => $w->URL,
>             );
>             $arr = array_merge($arr, $t);
>             $str[] = implode(',', array_keys($t));
>             foreach($w->REGIONS->REGION as $region)
>             {
>                 $t = array(
>                     ":rwineid$j" => $w->WINEID,
>                     ":region$j" => $region,
>                 );
>                 $region_arr = array_merge($region_arr, $t);
>                 $region_str[] = implode(',', array_keys($t));
>                 $j++ ;
>             }
>             foreach($w->OCCASIONS->OCCASION as $o)
>             {
>                 $t = array(
>                     ":owineid$k" => $w->WINEID,
>                     ":occasion$k" => $o,
>                 );
>                 $occasion_arr = array_merge($occasion_arr, $t);
>                 $occasion_str[] = implode(',', array_keys($t));
>                 $k++ ;
>             }
>             foreach($w->FLAVORS->FLAVOR as $f)
>             {
>                 $t = array(
>                     ":fwineid$l" => $w->WINEID,
>                     ":flavor$l" => $f,
>                 );
>                 $flavor_arr = array_merge($flavor_arr, $t);
>                 $flavor_str[] = implode(',', array_keys($t));
>                 $l++ ;
>             }
>             $i++ ;
>         }
>         $sql = " Delete from wines ;
>                                   Insert into wines (wineid,acctid,brandname,varietal,description,propreitaryname,color,caseproduction,url)
>                                   values
>                                   (".implode('), (', $str).") ;
>                                    Delete from wine_regions ;
>                                   Insert into wine_regions (wineid,region) values (".implode('), (', $region_str).") ;
>                                   Delete from wine_occasions ;
>                                   Insert into wine_occasions (wineid,occasion) values (".implode('), (', $occasion_str).") ;
>                                   Delete from wine_flavors ;
>                                   Insert into wine_flavors (wineid,flavor) values (".implode('), (', $flavor_str).") ;  " ;
>         $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql) ;
>         $command->bindValues($arr);
>         $command->bindValues($region_arr);
>         $command->bindValues($occasion_arr);
>         $command->bindValues($flavor_arr);
>         $command->execute() ;
>     }
> ```

Comment: I get this error with your code: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based

Comment: I added the following bit of code:    array_unshift($arr, '');array_unshift($region_arr, '');array_unshift($occasion_arr, '');array_unshift($flavor_arr, '');
        unset($arr[0]);unset($region_arr[0]);unset($occasion_arr[0]);unset($flavor_arr[0]);

Comment: As per the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014405/warning-pdostatementexecute-pdostatement-execute-sqlstatehy093-invali

I now get the same token mismatch error as before.

Comment: No, the problem not here, i'm understand my mistake. Give me some time

Comment: Hey, there was some other issue at the db level. COnfiguration. Resolved it now. Will accept your implementation and answer as it is cleaner. Thanks for your time!

Comment: No problem, but my solution really has a problem. I correct it. Ok, have a nice day